# Powershell Return only folders that exist

Tags: powershell

We are deleting a load of XP profiles to save disk space. Some profile folders for XP exist as well as those for the same user with the .V2 for windows 7. Id like to use powershell to return only those XP profiles that exist.

Here is my code so far

```
 $path = "\\server01\profiles"

#Get User Folder names into variable for ForEach Loop
$UserFolders = get-childitem -path $path\*.V2 | where-object {$_.Psiscontainer -eq "True"} |select-object name

#Loop through folders in Directory
foreach ($UserFolder in $UserFolders){
    #remove the last .V2 from the folder name
    $UserFolder = $UserFolder.name.substring(0,$UserFolder.name.length-3)
    write-output $path\$userfolder
            test-path $path\$userfolder #returns True or false
    }
```

I just cant get the last bit to work. How can I only display only those folders that exist (return True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to rearrange things so that `Write-Output` only occurs if `Test-Path` validates that a path exists. I won't add anything new to your code except for an if statement, as an example:

```
foreach ($UserFolder in $UserFolders){
    $UserFolder = $UserFolder.name.substring(0,$UserFolder.name.length-3)

    if (test-path $path\$userfolder)
    {
        # Code at this level will only be executed if Test-Path was true.
        write-output $path\$userfolder 
    }

}
```

So by placing `write-output` into the [scope](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) of the if statement, we ensure that it will only be executed if `Test-Path` is true.

Comment: As a side-note: always use `Test-Path -LiteralPath` unless you're certain you need to match patterns. I'd also recommend using `(Join-Path $path $userfolder)` rather than `$path\$userfolder`.